# T-SQL : Return variable amount of records based on the top value in a column

Tags: sql, t-sql

If I have table:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------+
|  Col 1                                     Col 2    Col 3  |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
|  a72195fa-57ca-4849-b423-5595219c8f6b      Val1     1      |
|  a72195fa-57ca-4849-b423-5595219c8f6b      Val2     1      |
|  a72195fa-57ca-4849-b423-5595219c8f6b      Val3     2      |
|  a72195fa-57ca-4849-b423-5595219c8f6b      Val4     3      |
|  2F6D0B9E-2221-4D18-A64E-ACCFB83EACC7      Val5     2      |
|  2F6D0B9E-2221-4D18-A64E-ACCFB83EACC7      Val6     2      |
|  2F6D0B9E-2221-4D18-A64E-ACCFB83EACC7      Val7     3      |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

For a given Col 1 Value, how do I return all records for smallest value in Col3. Meaning where `[Col 1] = a72195fa-57ca-4849-b423-5595219c8f6b`, I want to return:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------+
|  Col 1                                     Col 2    Col 3  |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
|  a72195fa-57ca-4849-b423-5595219c8f6b      Val1     1      |
|  a72195fa-57ca-4849-b423-5595219c8f6b      Val2     1      |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

And where `[Col 1] = 2F6D0B9E-2221-4D18-A64E-ACCFB83EACC7`, I want to return:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| Col 1                                   Col 2    Col 3  |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| 2F6D0B9E-2221-4D18-A64E-ACCFB83EACC7    Val5     2      |
| 2F6D0B9E-2221-4D18-A64E-ACCFB83EACC7    Val6     2      |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT A.*
FROM TABLE A,
(
SELECT Col1,MIN(Col3) AS Col3
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY Col1
) B
WHERE A.Col3=B.Col3;
```

Comment: I believe this is it. Thanks Venk!

Answer (score 2):

A bit smarter (i think):

```
SELECT * INTO #TEMP
FROM
(
 SELECT 'a72195fa-57ca-4849-b423-5595219c8f6b' col1, 'Val1' col2, 1 col3
UNION SELECT 'a72195fa-57ca-4849-b423-5595219c8f6b' col1, 'Val2' col2, 1 col3
UNION SELECT 'a72195fa-57ca-4849-b423-5595219c8f6b' col1, 'Val3' col2, 2 col3
UNION SELECT 'a72195fa-57ca-4849-b423-5595219c8f6b' col1, 'Val4' col2, 3 col3
UNION SELECT '2F6D0B9E-2221-4D18-A64E-ACCFB83EACC7' col1, 'Val5' col2, 2 col3
UNION SELECT '2F6D0B9E-2221-4D18-A64E-ACCFB83EACC7' col1, 'Val6' col2, 2 col3
UNION SELECT '2F6D0B9E-2221-4D18-A64E-ACCFB83EACC7' col1, 'Val7' col2, 3 col3
) A

SELECT * FROM #TEMP

SELECT *
FROM
(
 SELECT *
 , RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col3 ASC) _RANK
 FROM #TEMP
) a
WHERE a._RANK = 1
```

Comment: I approve of the window function (+1 here), but why the temp table?

Comment: That's the proof of concept (i.e. to allow anyone to test). Of course the original posted will skip the first two statements and adapt the third to their table/column names :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way using a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE Col3 = (SELECT MIN(Col3) FROM myTable WHERE Col1 = @SomePassedInGuid)
AND Col1 = @SomePassedInGuid
```

Comment: Sorry, that's just a coincidence, will edit to include guids as the keys

Comment: @TamarindoSean - Could you also expand your description of what exactly you are trying to achieve? It is a bit vague (and the reason you got two answers that are not as helpful as they could be).

Answer (score 0):

Here is basically the same query Lee gave, expressed a bit more compactly.

```
select top (1) with ties
  Col1, Col2, Col3
from T
order by rank() over (
  partition by Col1
  order by Col3
)
```